# Read Port number from configuration file under Remoting section

Tags: .net, remoting

I am trying to read the TCP port number from the `<system.runtime.remoting>` section (`channels\channel ref="tcp" port="9090"`) in `App.config`. The config file is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.runtime.remoting>
    <application Name="MyServer">
      <service>
        <wellknown mode="Singleton" type="MyServer.Servers.SvrConnection, MyServer" objectUri="MyConnection" />
      </service>
      <channels>
       <channel ref="tcp" port="9090">
          <serverProviders>
            <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full" />
          </serverProviders>
          <clientProviders>
            <formatter ref="binary" />
          </clientProviders>
        </channel>
      </channels>
    </application>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

How would I achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by reading the `App.config` as an XML document in C# and using the XML element to read the port number. Please advise if there is a better way to do this.